# Indy / Libssl32 access violation in SSL_accept at TIdTCPServer stop

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I use Delphi 10.1 Update 2 and Indy 10.6.2.5341.

We experience access violations in SSL_accept. This happens if a TIdTCPServer is setup using SSL and there is an open connection that has NOT yet negotiated TLS if the TIdTCPServer is stopped.

This looks like a problem in Libssl32 or Indy. This can be simply reproduced with the following code and Putty using a RAW connection. Does anyone knows a solution (or workaround) to prevent these crashes?

```
procedure TSslCrash.HandlerOnExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  //
end;

procedure TSslCrash.HandlerOnConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough := False;
end;

procedure TSslCrash.ButtonStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LServer := TIdTCPServer.Create;
  LIOHandler := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create;

  LIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmServer;
  LIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  LIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
  LIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
  LIOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'localhost.crt';
  LIOHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'localhost.crt';
  LIOHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'localhost.key';

  LServer.Bindings.Add.Port := 10000;
  LServer.IOHandler := LIOHandler;
  LServer.OnExecute := HandlerOnExecute;
  LServer.OnConnect := HandlerOnConnect;
  LServer.Active := True;

  //Now open a RAW connection with Putty on port 10000 and keep it open
end;

procedure TSslCrash.ButtonStopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(LServer) then begin
    LServer.Active := False;  //This causes an AV in TIdSSLSocket.Accept

    FreeAndNil(LIOHandler);
    FreeAndNil(LServer);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Workaround: use a reverse proxy which does the TLS/SSL stuff (Apache HTTP server), so you can use plain HTTP within your Delphi application

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a solution for us, because we're not able to ship Apache (or another reverse proxy) with our solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Putty is connected in Raw mode, there is no SSL/TLS handshake performed, so `SSL_accept()` is stuck waiting for a handshake request that never arrives.

When `TIdTCPServer` is being deactivated, it disconnects active socket connections, failing any blocking socket operations in progress in other threads.  In the case of `SSL_accept()`, that should unblock it so it can exit with an error code that `TIdSSLSocket.Accept()` can then detect and wrap into a raised exception (`EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError`, `EIdOSSLAcceptError`, `EIdSocketError`, etc depending on the nature of the error code) in the context of the client thread that is waiting for the handshake to complete.

However, when `TIdTCPServer` is disconnecting a socket connection during deactivation, `TIdTCPConnection.Disconnect()` is called, which calls `TIdIOHandler.Close()`, which `TIdSSLIOhandlerSocketOpenSSL` has overridden to free its internal `TIdSSLSocket` object - the same object that is calling `SSL_accept()`.  So it is quite likely that the underlying OpenSSL `SSL` object is being freed in `TIdSSLSocket.Destroy()` (which calls `SSL_shutdown()` and `SSL_free()`) in the context of the deactivating thread while still actively being used in `TIdSSLObject.Accept()` (which calls `SSL_accept()`) in the context of the client thread, thus causing an Access Violation.

There is not much that can be done about this without altering Indy's source code.  For instance, maybe change `TIdCustomTCPServer.DoTerminateContext()` to call `AContext.Binding.CloseSocket()` instead of `AContext.Connection.Disconnect(False)` so the `IOHandler` itself is not closed, just the underlying socket (similar to what `TIdCustomTCPServer.StopListening()` does when terminating its listening `accept()` threads).

I have opened a ticket in Indy's issue tracker for you:

[#218: Access Violation in SSL_accept() when deactivating TIdTCPServer](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/218)

Comment: Thanks Remy, that change in the Indy code solves this problem. I probably have found another problem (maybe bug, AV in Indy SSL code while destroying TIdContext when TIdTCPServer is being deactivated). I'll get back to you if I have a clear and simple reproduction.